# How to get the sum of a edge field in graph database using gremlin?

Tags: graph, gremlin, titan, vertices

I'm having two vertices Named - UserName and CompanyName, Whenever user visits any company I increases edge field (i.e pageVisit). for individual results i'm getting those pageVisit values but How can i get the Sum of all user pageVisits?

I want to show total Page Visits on a company page, I didn't find any way to add the edge values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [sum() step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/reference/#sum-step):

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> vUser1 = graph.addVertex("UserName","user1")
==>v[0]
gremlin> vUser2 = graph.addVertex("UserName","user2")
==>v[2]
gremlin> vCompany = graph.addVertex("CompanyName","Company")
==>v[4]
gremlin> vUser1.addEdge('visits',vCompany,'pageVisit',10)
==>e[6][0-visits->4]
gremlin> vUser2.addEdge('visits',vCompany,'pageVisit',20)
==>e[7][2-visits->4]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:3 edges:2], standard]
gremlin> g.V(vCompany).inE('visits').values('pageVisit').sum()
==>30
```

Comment: I'm using Rexster for adding pageVisit count, so it is saving as a string. How can I use sum() operator with string values ?

Comment: I don't think storing it as a string is a good idea. You should store the data in its native type.  Convert that string to number when you write it to the database.  Also note that this answer is in TinkerPop 3.x syntax and there is no Rexster in TinkerPop 3.x - you would instead use Rexster's replacement, Gremlin Server: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/reference/#gremlin-server